# File size too high

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on ipython notebook with a CSV file of 4gb. The file is yelp dataset review file. The file is taking too much time to get load with the help of panda.

Any suggestions to use other methods?

Comment: Can you share some code you are trying to execute that is taking too much time?

Comment: with files that size you need a database

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization.

Comment: In my experience, saving as `csv.gz` (one-off task), then reading into `panda` the `csv.gz` file improves performance. Even better would be to save as `pkl` or `pkl.gz`.